# Jquery Colorbox Not overlayable element

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I am using jQuery colorbox plugin and it opens a div at my page as well and background is dark as usual. However when user makes something I show notifications at my page and it goes under black background.

What should I do(with css) for my notification div for not to be overlayed by colorbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added that to my css and it works:

```
 z-index: 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your notification div needs to be a direct child of the body element and it needs to have a higher z-index value than the one colorbox is using.